# gcc compile stages with debug options

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, gdb

I am trying to study different compilation stage from GCC.

Compile stage by stage manually

```
$ g++ -E main.cpp -o main.i                  # I1

$ g++ -S main.i -o main.s                    # S1
$ g++ -S main.i -o main.debug.s -ggdb -g3    # S2

$ as main.s       -o main.as.o               # O1
$ as main.debug.s -o main.as.debug.o         # O2
```

And compile again with "g++ only" completely

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp -o main.gcc.o                  # G1
$ g++ -c main.cpp -o main.gcc.debug.o -ggdb -g3  # G2
```

At the end

**main.as.o** is identical with **main.gcc.o** without debug info

but

**main.as.debug.o** is very different from **main.gcc.debug.o**

Why? do I miss anything?

here is the tool version

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/lib/gcc/7 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-7 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-checking=release --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 7.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0)

$ as -v
Apple Inc version cctools-862, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

**UPDATE**

with -v and -save-temps options here shows the equivalent commands

```
#####

# $ g++ -E main.cpp -o main.i                # I1
$ cc1plus -E -quiet -v -D__DYNAMIC__ main.cpp -o main.i -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2

#####

# $ g++ -S main.i -o main.s                  # S1
$ cc1plus -fpreprocessed main.i -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase main.i -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip main.s -version -fdump-tree-all-graph -o main.s

#####

# $ g++ -S main.i -o main.debug.s -ggdb -g3  # S2
$ cc1plus -fpreprocessed main.i -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase maini -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip main.debug.s -ggdb -g3 -version -o main.debug.s

#####

$ as main.s       -o main.as.o               # O1
$ as main.debug.s -o main.as.debug.o         # O2

#####

# g++ -c main.cpp -o main.gcc.o                  # G1

$ cc1plus -E -quiet -v -D__DYNAMIC__ main.cpp -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -fpch-preprocess -o main.ii

$ cc1plus -fpreprocessed main.ii -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip main.gcc.o -version -o main.s

$ as -arch x86_64 -v -force_cpusubtype_ALL -o main.gcc.o main.s

#####

# g++ -c main.cpp -o main.gcc.debug.o -ggdb -g3  # G2

$ cc1plus -E -quiet -v -dD -D__DYNAMIC__ main.cpp -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -ggdb -g3 -fworking-directory -fpch-preprocess -o main.ii

$ cc1plus -fpreprocessed main.ii -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip main.gcc.debug.o -ggdb -g3 -version -o main.s

$ as -arch x86_64 -v -force_cpusubtype_ALL -o main.gcc.debug.o main.s

#####
```

Comment: You can use `-v` for `gcc` in addition to your normal options to see how it invokes the tools for you.

Comment: One difference I can spot is that your manual steps use /usr/bin/as while the "g++ only" step will use gcc's built-in assembler (you can tell it not to do that with the right command line options).

Comment: So try compiling using `g++ -v -Wall -g main.cpp -o mainprog`

Comment: with -v option: "g++ only" step  uses the same "as"

Comment: @JesperJuhl gcc does not have a "builtin-in assembler", you are confusing with clang.

Comment: @Marc Glisse - whoops, you are correct. Thank you for the correction. It does have a built-in pre-processor though. ;-)

Comment: In your last update, if you manually run the commands that `g++ -g -v main.cpp` printed out, do you get a `.o` that matches letting the compiler front-end invoke all the tools?  Also, is `main.debug.s` the same as the save-temps `.s`?

Comment: Can you summarize whether using the commands printed by `g++ -v` "solved the problem"?  Is there still anything unexplained?  Clearly g++ passes some options you weren't using, but do those options explain what you see?  It's pretty dense going trying to read your table.  The double-spacing doesn't help, it makes the grouping into blocks less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Oooops, it is trivial failure by me.

Original post

```
$ g++ -E main.cpp -o main.i                  # I1

$ g++ -S main.i -o main.s                    # S1
$ g++ -S main.i -o main.debug.s -ggdb -g3    # S2
```

I need to call -E also with debug options and serve to the next stage....

Should change to...

```
$ g++ -E main.cpp -o main.debug.i  -ggdb -g3       # I2

$ g++ -S main.debug.i -o main.debug.s -ggdb -g3    # S2'
```

then the following stages will generate same machine code...

Comment: What did you do in `main.cpp` that's *preprocesses* differently with `-g`?  Does `libc++` `#ifdef` some debug code like `std::vector` range-checking or something when `-O0 -g` is set?

Comment: no, just very simple test without any std lib. There are class definition and macro. Gcc will in general put a lot of stuff for debugging (with -g) in pre-processing step. (And I did not realized that -g has already affected pre-processing i.e. .ii generation and still used usual .ii file for further compilation)

Comment: On x86-64 Linux compiling `hello.c` (stdio.h and a main() that uses printf), I get identical `gcc -E` output with/without `-g`.  I tried `gcc` and with `g++` as well.  gcc7.1.  Maybe it's different when targeting Darwin / its libc instead of Linux / glibc?